# Firebase Realtime DB - how to show progress bar on image view till image loads and disappear once image is successfully loaded?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-progressbar, firebaseui

In my android app, I want to add progress bar on each images, during image loads from firebase relatime database. Once image loads successfully, I need to make progress bar invisible.

Please help with code.

I have developed Android code to fetch image and text from Firebase relatime database, using recycler view and card view.

XML:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/post_image" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>
```

Main activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mBloglist;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Industries");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mBloglist = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myrecycleview);
        mBloglist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBloglist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Industry, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Industry, BlogViewHolder>
                (Industry.class, R.layout.blog_row, BlogViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Industry model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getIndustryName());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getIndustryDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getIndustryImage());

            }
        };
        mBloglist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc)
        {
            TextView post_desc = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
        {
           ImageView post_Image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_Image);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, not sure if this works.

1. add an id to your progress bar in XML. for an instance, let's assume its id is progressBar.

solution 1:
make progress bar global and create its instance in onCreate method.

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Industry, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Industry, BlogViewHolder>
            (Industry.class, R.layout.blog_row, BlogViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Industry model, int position) {
            mProgressbar.show();
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getIndustryName());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getIndustryDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getIndustryImage());
            mProgressBar.dismiss();
        }
    };
    mBloglist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Solution 2:
declare progress bar in `BlogViewHolder` 
inside viewholder

```
public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
    {
       mProgressbar.show();
       ImageView post_Image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
       Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_Image);
       mProgressbar.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso Callback for this purpose.
Add progress bar over your image in your layout and then modify your `setImage` function

```
public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
{
   ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageProgress);
   mProgress.show();
   ImageView post_Image =(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
   Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_Image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess() {
       //Image loaded successfully, now dismiss progress bar.
       mProgress.dismiss();
     }

     @Override
     public void onError() {
       //Image Not Loaded properly
       Picasso.with(ctx).load(errorImage).into(post_Image);
     }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use visibility property of progress bar. 
Firstly add your progress bar to layout and make its visibility 'Visibility.GONE'.
Then when you start downloading make visibility 'Visibility.VISIBLE'. After finishing download make visibility 'Visibility.GONE'.